# Trying to Update a record from a php script

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a record from a php script if the checkbox pendinginput_c is selected. I cannot get the record to update from the script. However if I type the exact command below in the mysql console then the record updates correctly.

```
                if($bean->pendinginput_c == 'on')
            {
            $sql = "UPDATE cases SET status='Pending Input' WHERE id='958ca4e5-51'";
            }
```

Further up in the script you will see there are other sql statements that are currently working. No updates, just selects.

```
$sql_nmb = "SELECT case_number FROM cases where id='".$bean->parent_id."'";
            $result = $bean->db->query($sql_nmb, true);
            $case = $bean->db->fetchByAssoc($result);               

            $sql = 'SELECT c.assigned_user_id , c.id , cc.contact_id as contact_id, co.first_name , co.last_name , ear.email_address_id ,ea.email_address FROM cases as c 
                        LEFT JOIN contacts_cases as cc on c.id = cc.case_id
                        LEFT JOIN contacts as co on co.id = contact_id
                        LEFT JOIN email_addr_bean_rel ear ON ear.bean_id = contact_id
                        LEFT JOIN email_addresses as ea on ea.id = ear.email_address_id
                        WHERE c.id = "'.$bean->parent_id.'" and cc.deleted = 0 and ear.deleted = 0 and ea.deleted = 0';
            $resp = $bean->db->query($sql, true);
```

Comment: where's your mysql_query() method ?!

Comment: SQL queries don't get executed just because you place them somewhere in your code.

Comment: I have edited my original post to show you further up in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($bean->pendinginput_c == 'on'){
    $sql = "UPDATE cases SET status='Pending Input' WHERE id='958ca4e5-51'";
    $bean->db->query($sql, true); 
}
```

Additionally check that $bean->pendinginput_c really equals "on". echo it above the if statement to double check.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the `'`'s in the query like this: `\'`?

EDIT: Assuming of course you are actually DOING the query with `mysql_query($sql)`... Or some other query function.